# How to avoid keyboard from appearing with starting FilePickerActivity

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, filepicker.io, filepicker

I have a button in an activity that starts a `FilePickerActivity`. Everything works as expected except for the soft keyboard that appears right when the activity starts. I've already tried using the following code line but I can't use it INSIDE the FilePickerActivity because I can't modify it: `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`

Is there an extra that I can put in the intent or something to tell that `FilePickerActivity` to NOT open the soft keyboard on start?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in your activity tag in manifest:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`

Comment: It was set to "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"", thank you for your answer! I forgot to check the manifest

Comment: happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in manifest activity tag